# how to call a tcl file from another tcl file

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, tcl, exec

i need to call a tcl file which hold the code for capturing image from another tcl file.

for example i  my image.tcl file code is as follow :

```html
proc image {}  { 

set time [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y%m%d_%H%M%S]
   
exec ffmpeg -f dshow -s 1280x720 -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -benchmark c:/test/sample_$time.jpg
 
}
image
```

so, i want to call this image.tcl file from another tcl file called main.tcl,so the code for main.tcl can be as follow:

```html
proc a {}  { 

"c:/test/image.tcl"

"c:/test/video.tcl" 

"c:/test/live.tcl"
 
}
a
```

the above tcl script should run one after another when i call main.tcl

any solution for this. add the code as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`source`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/source.htm).

In main.tcl, you will have:

```
proc a {}  { 
    source "c:/test/image.tcl"
    source "c:/test/video.tcl" 
    source "c:/test/live.tcl"
}
a
```

Comment: Be careful with calling `image` from the image.tcl file however. You might be running the same thing twice if you call `image` again in main.tcl. When you use `source`, you will be able to use the proc from the sourced file.